# What does "label_replace" do in this request, how does it work?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have an alert in Prometheus, but I don't understand what it does. Who can explain its function?

```
label_replace(changes(hikaricp_connections_timeout_total[5m]) > 2 or absent(hikaricp_connections) == 1, "ip", "$1", "instance", "([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?")
```

Answer (score 0):

From Prometheus' [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace):

> For each timeseries in `v`, `label_replace(v instant-vector, dst_label string, replacement string, src_label string, regex string)`
> matches the [regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) `regex` against the value of the label `src_label`. If it
> matches, the value of the label `dst_label` in the returned timeseries will be the expansion
> of `replacement`, together with the original labels in the input. Capturing groups in the
> regular expression can be referenced with `$1`, `$2`, etc. Named capturing groups in the regular expression can be referenced with `$name` (where `name` is the  capturing group name). If the regular expression doesn't match then the timeseries is returned unchanged.

So in your case query `changes(hikaricp_connections_timeout_total[5m]) > 2 or absent(hikaricp_connections) == 1` will be firstly evaluated.

Then label `instance` from its resulting vectors will be matched against regex `([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?`. And for those vectors that contain label matching it, new label `ip` will be added with first captured group of the match (in this example everything from the beginning of the string before colon).